# Unable to unpublish certain pages from CME

Tags: cme

Not able to unpublish certain pages from cms, the status is showing success but in CME these are still showing with published icon, so I cannot remove these, please help

Comment: Pages may be still published on other target .Select any page click on "where used" and inside "published to" tab you can fine where page is still published.

Comment: I have checked that,, one some publications the pages published on one target, I tried unpublishing these receptively, the status of unpublishing is true but still the pages is not unpublished in CMS

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible likely causes for this:

1. The Page is still published to another Publishing Target, or
2. The Structure Group that the Page is inside is set to not be publishable (or unpublishable!)

As Abdul says, you can check the first of these by checking the `Published to` tab of the `Where Used` dialogue.

You can check for the second possibility by looking at the `Publishable` checkbox against the  `Properties` of the containing Structure Group. If this is the case, then you'll notice that the Success status appears *very quickly* in the Publishing Queue against this Page (as it does not try to render or deploy the Page).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi,, thanks for the reply, actually the pages are coming from a parent publication and these are not localized in any publication(same is the case with the SGs) but when i try unpublishing the pages are getting unpublished from some publications but not in 1-2 publications.

Comment: Do the Pages show in the Publishing Queue for those Publications (the ones that they're not being unpublished from)?

Comment: Yes these are showing in publication and status is passign through all stages as well

Comment: If there is nothing in the `Published to` tab of the `Where Used` dialogue but the globe icon is still showing on the Page (even after clearing your browser cache) then I'd suggest that you raise this with Tridion Support.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I checked it again, on trying unpublishing items these are not getting removed from the published to tab in CMS, though the status is showing success, I tried creating a new page and publish it,, when I unpublished it again it the globe icon got removed

Comment: Great. When you say "when I unpublished it again the globe icon got removed", do you mean from the 2nd page that you created or from the original, problematic page?

Comment: I got the issue Jonathan,, it was because the page was published on more than one CT/PTs, In the published to tab it was showing the duplicate entries so i tried rollback of the pages to certain dates based on the published to tab and then unpublish these with this these got removed. Please write the anwer of this question with your comment: If there is nothing in the Published to tab of the Where Used dialogue but the globe icon is still showing on the Page (even after clearing your browser cache) then I'd suggest that you raise this with Tridion Support.... I will accept the answer,, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Besides everything that Jonathan explained, there is still one more option to consider, and that is **WHERE PAGE WAS PUBLISHED**

What that means is:

1. you publish page to target `live` in publication A, B and C
2. you remove publication B from target `live`
3. if you try to unpublish page from all publications, resolver will pick only publications A and C, since they are currently only added to `live` target. That way your page will indefinitely stay published in publication B on target Live.

To fix this issue, you again need to add publication B to target `Live`, unpublish it, and then again remove it. Please check if this is something similar to your situation.